# Pinch zoom on a xamarin forms scrollview

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview, pinchzoom

Im working on an application in which we have a xamarin forms scrollview to which we add several subviews. Each of this subviews has a custom renderer defined in the droid project, as we render some pretty complex objects (adorned text displayed as a elaborated poligon for example).

Now I am required to add pinch zoom for that scrollview (yay me!) is there a practical way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your time.